# ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "MongoId" from namespace

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, mongodb-query, doctrine-odm

I'm using Symfony2 with the DoctrineMongoDbBundle

I get the following error when trying to use `new MongoId()`

```
ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "MongoId" from namespace "..." in ...Controller.php line 64. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?
```

The code in my controller is

```
// connect
$m = $this->container->get('doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_connection');

// select a database
$db = $m->selectDatabase('db');

// select a collection (analogous to a relational database's table)
$collection = $db->createCollection('Entity');

// find everything in the collection
$entity = $collection->findOne(array('_id' => new MongoId($id)));
```

I can use mongodb perfectly well with the ODM and if I remove the query it works fine too, i.e.

```
$entity = $collection->findOne();
```

Any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a backslash to get the correct scope :

```
$collection->findOne(array('_id' => new \MongoId($id)))
```

the `\` is telling PHP to use the root namespace rather than yours.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly, had been going slightly mad trying to solve this